# Auth::user returns null (or Page Expired) in Laravel 5.8 via Stripe webhook

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I cannot get my Laravel setup to find my authenticated user in my StripeController. I am trying to set up a Stripe webhook to perform an action once a successful payment has been made.

I have done lots of reading on similar issues but after trying fixes I've read, most of them contiue to return null.

My latest attempt is below which returns `status code 419` and `Page Expired`.

**StripeController.php**

```
class StripeController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
      \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    }

    public function paymentSuccess()
    {
      // The commented code fetches the first User OK but I want the logged in user.

      // $userDetails = User::first();
      // $userDetails->is_subscribed = 1;
      // $userDetails->save();

      //This always returns null, as does any other user() command.
      return Auth::user();  
    }

    public function createSession(Request $request)
    {

        $session =  \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
          "success_url" => "https://www.mymarketingwizard.io/#/dashboard",
          "cancel_url" => "https://example.com/cancel",
          "payment_method_types" => ["card"],
          "line_items" => [[
            "name" => "Lifetime Access",
            "description" => "Lifetime Access",
            "amount" => 15000,
            "currency" => "gbp",
            "quantity" => 1
          ]]
        ]);

        return $session;

      }
```

My login script:
**AuthController.php**

```
 public function login(Request $request)
   {
       $request->validate([
           'email' => 'required|string|email',
           'password' => 'required|string'
       ]);
       $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
       $credentials['active'] = 1;
       $credentials['deleted_at'] = null;

       if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))

        return response()->json(['error' => 'unauthorized'],404);


       $user = $request->user();
       $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
       $token = $tokenResult->token;
       if ($request->remember_me)
           $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
       $token->save();
       return response()->json([

           'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
           'token_type' => 'Bearer',
           'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
               $tokenResult->token->expires_at
           )->toDateTimeString()
       ]);
   }
```

I have read lots of other similar questions about this issue, many pointing towards a `'middleware' => 'web'` must be used where  you want to access `Auth::user` so this is my latest attempt:

**api.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/'], function () {

  Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {

      Route::auth();

 Route::post('paymentSuccess','StripeController@paymentSuccess'); // Route I'm a hitting via Stripe
  });

    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('send-token', 'AuthController@sendToken');
    Route::post('validate-token', 'AuthController@validateToken');
    Route::post('reset-password', 'AuthController@resetPassword');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
        Route::post('session','StripeController@createSession');
```

I have also read other solutions about moving the `'web'` classes out of `middlewareGroups` and into global `middleware` in the Kernel.php but that also did't work for me.

**Kernel.php**

```
namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Spatie\Cors\Cors::class,


    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,

        ],

        'api' => [

            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,

    ];

    /**
     * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
     *
     * This forces non-global middleware to always be in the given order.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewarePriority = [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    ];
}
```

**Payment.vue** 
This is my Vue Component which creates the Stripe session when the component is first created.  When the user clicks the `proceed to checkout` button, the method is executed.

```
 methods: {
    checkout() {
      stripe
        .redirectToCheckout({

          sessionId: this.sessionId.id
        })
        .then(result => {
          // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
          // error, display the localized error message to your customer
          // using `result.error.message`.
        })
    }
  },
   created() {
    api
      .post('/session')
      .then(response => {
        this.sessionId = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => {
      })
  }
```

My goal is to update my Users' table to say that the user who processed the payment is now subscribed.

Comment: It's a webhook, meaning that Stripe makes a HTTP call to your server after some action. There's no currently logged in user when the call is made.

Comment: If I make a test payment through my website, as a logged in user, I still get the same result.  I would expect it to return the user who is logged into the front end?

Comment: You'll need to get Stripe to pass the user details (email address, if it's unique) to you in the webhook and then use that to get the user from the DB.

Comment: But what happens if my user gives a different email upon paying than the one they signed up to my service with?

Comment: You'll pass the reference to Stripe when you initialize the transaction. Stripe will return the reference in the webhook. It's not necessarily email address, but that should work as long as it's set up correctly.

Comment: If I could see the controller action that initializes the payment, I could provide some more help.

Comment: Thank you - I've added my Javascript function that creates the Stripe session, and I've added the function in Laravel (StripeConttroller) where the session is executed.

Comment: Did you tried applying `$this->middleware('auth')` in your StripeController constructor?

Comment: Rocky - just tried that, and I got this response: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.mymarketingwizard.io/api/login" />

        <title>Redirecting to https://www.mymarketingwizard.io/api/login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="https://www.mymarketingwizard.io/api/login">https://www.mymarketingwizard.io/api/login</a>.
    </body>
</html>

Comment: Can't you pass the order id in metadata content? In webhook, you could check the corresponding order id received in metadata and update corresponding subscription for the user who created subscription.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when CSRF check failed. Add your webhook endpoint as an exception in **VerifyCsrfToken** middleware:

```
    protected $except = [
        'paymentSuccess',
    ];
```